# How to pass the selected value to java script function inside of select tag in html?

Tags: javascript

```
<form>
<SELECT NAME="sel" onChange="split(selected value)">
<OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
<OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
<OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
<OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
</SELECT>
</form>
```

Hi i need to pass the selected value immediately on inside of this select tag so pls some one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the value directly to the handler but you can get the values in it, I'd recommend to do this in code and not use inline event handlers:

```
var select = document.forms[0].sel;
select.onchange = function(){
   var value =  select.options[select.selectedIndex].value; // to get Value
   var text =  select.options[select.selectedIndex].text; // to get Text
}
```

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2SrV/

Answer (score 2):

**Not that I agree with how you're doing things here** (in side the tag), technically it is possible to do what you ask by the following:

```
<form>
<SELECT NAME="sel" onChange="split(this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
<OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
<OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
<OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
</SELECT>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function split(value)
{
  alert(value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<SELECT NAME="sel" onChange="split(value)">
<OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
<OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
<OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
<OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
</SELECT>
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

use "value". hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

`this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

*assuming you want to put it inline inside the onchange attribute