# Pass <select> value to function parameter

Tags: javascript

I have select cars in my form. How to pass its value to change function like parameter?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;
    </script>    

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function change()
        {
        a=5
        b=6
        update();
        }

        function update()
        {

        var returns = document.getElementById("returns");
        returns.value =a;

        var status = document.getElementById("status");
        status.value = b;
        }
    </script>

    <form>
    <input type="button" value="change" onclick="change()">
    <input type="text" name="returns" id="returns">
    <input type="text" name="status" id="status">
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you've got an extra <script> tag

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815198/how-to-pass-the-selected-value-to-java-script-function-inside-of-select-tag-in-h

Comment: Pass `this` into `change` call inside `onclick` attribute, then use DOM methods on `this` inside `change`.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the extra script tag (which is wrong) you can get the value of a `select` element using `javascript` like:

**html**

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
var cars = document.getElementById("cars");
var carSelected = cars.options[cars.selectedIndex].value;
```

Or as mentioned by @RickHitchcock just use `cars.value`.

Comment: You could also simply do `cars.value`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Thanks, I updated my answer :). you are right!

Comment: I think `selectedIndex` was needed for IE6, but hopefully no one's using that anymore : )

Comment: Hahaha.. I am working at a University.. you would be surprised what they are still using..

Comment: But I would like to make JavaScript function independent from html and pass variable value just in  <input type="button" value="change" onclick="change()">

Comment: Then use `document.getElementByTagName` instead. (if you use `onclick="change()"` you also make JavaScript dependent on the html... but ok)